# simple javascript node.js not entering function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, heroku

Starting a simple app using heroku and node.js. I'd like to display the text that is entered in the text box, but the function to do this never seems to enter. A reference error shows up when I inspect the element saying addString() is not defined. Am I missing something here?

Edit: put server-side and client side in separate files:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

var fs = require('fs');

var script = fs.readFileSync('./feed.js');
app.get('/feed.js', function(req, res) {
  res.type('text/javascript');
  res.send(script);
});

var html = "";


html += "<body>";
html += "<div> Tweet!";

html += "<input type= 'text' name = 'name' id = 'name_id'/>";

html += "<button type='button' id='submit' onclick='addString()'>Tweet</button>";
html += "</div>";

html += "</body>";

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send(html);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

And feed.js:

```
var input = [];

function addString() {
    console.log("got here");
    alert("got here");
    var s = document.getElementById("name_id").value;//x.name.value;
    input.push(s);
    var size = s.length;
    //alert(size);
    printArray(size);
}

function printArray(size){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    for (var i = 0 ; i < size; ++i) {
        div.innerHTML += input[i] + "<br />";
    }
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    //alert(size);
}
```

Still does not seem to enter the feed.js functions

Answer (score 0):

`addString()` is a function you've defined in your server code; you didn't send it to the client along with the HTML. Use your favorite browser debugging tool to look at the code you're getting from the server.